# Webpack modules building error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: heroku, webpack, node-modules

I am deploying on heroku instance. One of the step uses `webpack` and fails during modules building. Is it possible to get more details other than next general error? Using `--display-error-details` doesn't help.

> One or more errors occurred. (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

```
remote: webpack --progress --display-error-details
remote: isDashboardMode? false
remote: isDevBuild? true
remote: Hash: da11b9b5f7b728252ffdd4bc0b7fbe62e7a1cee2
remote: Version: webpack 2.2.1
remote: Child
remote:     Hash: da11b9b5f7b728252ffd
remote:     Time: 29398ms
remote:                  Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
remote:                   0.js  7.13 kB       0  [emitted]
remote:         main-client.js  1.97 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  main-client
remote:               0.js.map   6.5 kB       0  [emitted]
remote:     main-client.js.map  2.24 MB       1  [emitted]         main-client
remote: Child
remote:     Hash: d4bc0b7fbe62e7a1cee2
remote:     Time: 22022ms
remote:              Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
remote:               0.js  15.9 kB       0  [emitted]
remote:     main-server.js  5.13 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  main-server
remote: aspnetcore-angular2-universal-starter@1.0.0-beta.6 /tmp/tmp.ypY0oo0Amq
remote: ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.5
remote: ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.5
remote: ├─┬ angular2-universal-polyfills@2.1.0-rc.1
remote: │ ├── es6-promise@3.0.2
remote: │ └── reflect-metadata@0.1.2
remote: └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.2
remote:  17% [0] building modules 80/204 modules 124 active ...js/mo
One or more errors occurred. 
(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)
```